# Typo3 6.2 RTE in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, typo3, rte

I have 4.4 updated to 6.2.15. And the RTE doesn't work in Chrome (45). But the problem is in the version 4.4 the same. I checked the user options and I tried to change the BE compress option in Install tool. I played with the options in the extension options.

In Firefox will it work. I have no idea anymore and I search in the whole internet.

Comment: Someone has changed the Typo3 core.

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome 73.0.3683.103 in a newly installation of typo3 7.6 for testing a new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all cache in TYPO3 and clear your browser cache - you should allways do this after an upgrade. You properly still have a compressed version of the JS file in your typo3_temp folder or a cached version in your browsers cache memory